# problem with multiple page routing in WASM

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor

i have a razor page with multiple rounting entry:

```
@page "/profile"
@page "/profile/user/{UserIdParam}"
@page "/profile/exchange/{ExchangeIdParam}"
```

when i am going to navigate to this routes is fine and worked,but when i need back to caller page , my routing not working.
my back button click code:

```
protected void NavigateToOverviewUserAndExchange()
 {
  if (UserId !=0)
   {
    NavigationManager.NavigateTo("usermanager");
    return;
   }
  else if (ExchangeId != 0)
   {
    NavigationManager.NavigateTo("exchange");
    return;
   }
 }
```

page url before back button click is:

```
http:.../profile/exchange/5
```

and after click back button, page url is :

```
http:.../profile/exchange/exchange
```

If i add a slash to begin of page name , is fine but it reload page from server.
another problem in this routing when i click on a link on menu then the page is reloaded from server again!
my link code:

```
 <a href="/usermanager">
  <i class="bi bi-circle"></i><span>Users</span>
 </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I forget to add this tag :

```
<base href="/" />
```

to index.html, after i added this tag then my problem was solved